# Use certain style only when the Fall Creators Update is detected

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

As an example, I would like to apply the `ButtonRevealStyle` to my button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="38" ... />
```

This will work, but of course only on a device with the Fall Creators Update installed. How do I disable this for all previous versions of W10?

I know I can use `.IsApiPresent()` in the code-behind when I want to check for a specific Windows Api but in this case this doesn't seem to be the preferred/recommended solution and I'd like to stick to just XAML for this. Doing it in C# requires referencing every single control with that style in code-behind and manually assigning the style if it's present. I'm pretty sure this is not the best solution in this day and age, where you can set up responsive and animated layouts solely in XAML. Besides, if the button was in a ListView.ItemTemplate just accessing each control would require a few solid lines of code. Not to mention the check itself

Is it possible? Am I missing something?

***Edit:*** Turns out it is possible, and I totally was missing something. Conditional XAML can easily be done and isn't that complex all things considered. It's just a matter of setting a custom namespace in the file (pointing to the same resource as the 'root' namespace, just with the `IsApiContractPresent" check at the end. Yes, it *is* possible to use that in XAML.

After setting the custom namespace you can then specify attributes that will only be aplied when the certain API is present on the End-User's device. Example:

```
xmlns:fcu="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,5)"
...
<Button fcu:Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="38" ... />
```

This will result in the button getting Reveal only on PCs with Fall Creators Update and the previous versions won't be throwing an error.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml

You people clearly like your downvote button a bit too much.

Comment: It requires referencing every single control with that style in code-behind and manually assigning the style if it's present. I'm pretty sure this is not the best solution in this day and age, where you can set up responsive and animated layouts solely in XAML.

Edit: Besides, if the button was in a `ListView.ItemTemplate` just accessing each control wopuld require a few solid lines of code. Not to mention the check itself

Comment: You may wish to add that detail to your post.

Comment: I assumed that was obvious.

Comment: It's impossible. There are some cases where you must increase your app's Minimum Version in order to use new features. any new resource keys added to generic.xaml and not available in a previous version. The version of generic.xaml used at runtime is determined by the OS version the device is running on. You can't use runtime API checks to determine the presence of XAML resources. So, you must only use resource keys that are available in the minimum version that your app supports or a XAMLParseException will cause your app to crash at runtime.

Comment: You could check the unsupported scenarios in MSDN document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFTActually, no. You can totally do it with XAML without changing the Minimum OS version. Turns out you can actually use the `IsApiContractPresent()` check directly in XAML while declaring a namespace. Here's more info if you want to read more about the topic:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml

Comment: @Reynevan So, you have used this way to resolve your issues. Right?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFTYes. It's pretty much what you linked, but done with XAML.

Comment: very valid question! why so many downvotes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is possible, and I totally was missing something. Conditional XAML can easily be done and isn't that complex all things considered. It's just a matter of setting a custom namespace in the file (pointing to the same resource as the 'root' namespace, just with the `IsApiContractPresent" check at the end. Yes, it *is* possible to use that in XAML.

After setting the custom namespace you can then specify attributes that will only be aplied when the certain API is present on the End-User's device. Example:

```
xmlns:fcu="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,5)"
...
<Button fcu:Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="38" ... />
```

This will result in the button getting Reveal only on PCs with Fall Creators Update and the previous versions won't be throwing an error.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml